# Hypertoric varieties in dimension 4?

Tags: toric-varieties, geometric-representation-theory, holomorphic-symplectic, hyperkaehler

Are the only smooth hypertoric varieties in real dimension 4 obtained
as minimal resolutions of type A simple singularities $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_{/n}$?